# ASP CDO 80040213 intermittent error only on one sub domain

Tags: asp-classic, smtp, gmail

I've been sending emails through classic asp pages using CDO for years now, but a few days ago I started getting "80040213 The transport failed to connect to the server" errors.

I can paste the code but that can't be the problem because it's worked for years and I don't get the error on my test website (http://test.xxxxx.com) and also after puzzling over it for hours I restarted the server and it started working again.

But it happened again yesterday, and I restarted the sever several times and it didn't start working again.

It's a google apps account, I've tried using SMTP ports 25, 465 and 578. All three work fine on my test. site, but none work on my www. site.

It's on a Windows Server 2003 R2.

The website sends around 200 emails per day.

I've tried creating a new user on that domain and also using my private gmail account, again this worked on the test. site but made no difference on my www. site.

Then I just restarted my server again, and it's started working!

Here is the code just in case (I can't post the full code because it contains too many links):

```
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("configuration/sendusing") = 2
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("configuration/smtpauthenticate") =1
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("configuration/sendusername") = "xxx"
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("configuration/sendpassword") = "xxx"
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
```

Comment: Next time it happens try using Telnet to test SMTP Communication https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718(v=exchg.65).aspx   I suspect it is environmental rather than code.  Maybe you are hitting the rate limit for that account, although even for a trial user it is 500 emails a day https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en